# Is a software token a valid second factor in multi-factor security?

Tags: language-agnostic, authentication

We are changing our remote log-in security process at my workplace, and we are concerned that the new system does not use [multi-factor authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication) as the old one did. (We had been using RSA key-fobs, but they are being replaced due to cost.) The new system is an anti-phishing image system which has been misunderstood to be a two-factor authentication system. We are now exploring ways to continue providing multi-factor security without issuing hardware devices to the users.

Is it possible to write a software-based token system to be installed on the user's PCs that would constitute a true second factor in a multi-factor authentication system? Would this be considered "something the user has", or would it simply be another form of "something the user knows"?

Edit: *phreakre* makes a good point about cookies. For the sake of this question, assume that cookies have been ruled out as they are not secure enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say "no". I don't think you can really get the "something you have" part of multi-factor authentication without issuing something the end user can carry with them. If you "have" something, it implies it can be lost - not many users lose their entire desktop machines. The security of "something you have", after all, comes from the following:

- you would notice when you don't have it - a clear indication security has been compromised
- only 1 person can have it. So if you do, someone else doesn't

Software tokens do not offer the same guarantees, and I would not in good conscience class it as something the user "has".

Answer (score 1):

While I am not sure it is a "valid" second factor, many websites have been using this type of process for a while: cookies. Hardly secure, but it is the type of item you are describing.

Insofar as regarding "something the user has" vs "something the user knows", if it is something resident on the user PC [like a background app providing information when asked but not requiring the user to do anything], I would file it under "things the user has". If they are typing a password into some field and then typing another password to unlock the information you are storing on their PC, then it is "something the user knows".

With regards to commercial solutions out there already in existence: We use a product for windows called BigFix. While it is primarily a remote configuration and compliance product, we have a module for it that works as part of our multi-factor system for remote/VPN situations.

Answer (score 1):

A software token is a second factor, but it probably isn't as good choice a choice as a RSA fob.  If the user's computer is compromised the attacker could silently copy the software token without leaving any trace it's been stolen (unlike a RSA fob where they'd have to take the fob itself, so the user has a chance to notice it's missing).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @freespace that the the image is not part of the multi-factor authentication for the user.  As you state the image is part of the anti-phishing scheme.  I think that the image is actually a weak authentication of the system to the user.  The image provides authentication to the user that the website is valid and not a fake phishing site.

> Is it possible to write a software-based token system to be installed on the user's PCs that would constitute a true second factor in a multi-factor authentication system?

The software based token system sounds like you may want to investigate the Kerberos protocol, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol).  I am not sure if this would count as a multi-factor authentication, though.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is something the *computer* has, not the user. 
So you can supposedly (depending on implementation) be assured that it is the computer, but no assurance regarding the user...

Now, since we're talking about remote login, perhaps the situation is personal laptops? In which case, *the laptop* is the something you have, and of course the password to it as something you know... Then all that remains is secure implementation, and that can work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Security is always about trade-offs.  Hardware tokens may be harder to steal, but they offer no protection against network-based MITM attacks.  If this is a web-based solution (I assume it is, since you're using one of the image-based systems), you should consider something that offer mutual https authentication.  Then you get protection from the numerous DNS attacks and wi-fi based attacks.

You can find out more here:
http://www.wikidsystems.com/learn-more/technology/mutual_authentication
and
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication
and here is a tutorial on setting up mutual authentication to prevent phishing:
http://www.howtoforge.net/prevent_phishing_with_mutual_authentication.

The image-based system is pitched as mutual authentication, which I guess it is, but since it's not based on cryptographic principals, it's pretty weak.  What's to stop a MITM from presenting the image too?  It's less than user-friendly IMO too.

Comment: Not completely accurate, something-you-have, if done properly, DOES protect against network based attacks. For instance, cryptographic smartcards. Where you're right, is pseudo-2ndfactor, like RSA securid. That doesnt stop MITM...

Comment: On the other hand, your point on "image authentication" is well placed. I've been raging against that machine for some time, I dont understand why its not obvious.