# software (virtual token) 2 factor authentication?

Tags: authentication, hipaa

my company has been exploring implementing 2FA for our websites.  After reviewing several products and the 2FA wiki page, it seems like a Virtual token is the cheapest solution that supposedly fulfills my requirements which are:

1. Not a hardware token (so no yubikey, securid, etc.), but this is due to cost restrictions
2. No software to be installed by the client, such as a Java Applet, ActiveX plugin, exe to run on the desktop
3. Most likely cannot use a "grid" (may not be 508 compliant)
4. Does not require user to have a phone (rules out google auth and a number of other mobile based solutions)
5. Non-biometric (since it will most likely need hardware or software install)
6. If we must violate 1), it must be easy to deploy and cheap (our user lists are constantly changing [by project] and in very different locations)

I have looked at a few "virtual tokens" including "Sestus" and I cannot see how these are "true" 2fa.  It doesn't require the install of any software and is entirely browser based.  The 2fa is based on the information obtainable through the browser such as the user agent, which seems easily spoofable.

I found a similar question here: [Is a software token a valid second factor in multi-factor security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72540/is-a-software-token-a-valid-second-factor-in-multi-factor-security) but it is over 2 years old.

At this point, is the most viable and cost effective solution to go with yubikeys?

Comment: Seems like it'd be more cost-effective and simpler to break #4 unless your apps are targeted to people who don't have cellphones.

Answer (score 0):

Sestus' Virtual Token(R) solution IS a true multi-factor authentication approach.  It is used by FFIEC, HIPPA, CJIS, and PCI regulated companies, including the U.S. Department of the Treasury.  Virtual Token(r) MFA does place something on the user's device, a mathematic key.  It accomplishes this using software the user already has (their browser).  So, no new software must be deployed to the user.